# How to make an inner join efficient mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, inner-join

I'm having two tables called 
1. Table A - with multiple columns, having primary key as user_id (900,000+ records)
2. Table B - with single column called user_id (900+ records)

The table A contains all user_id 's of table B and more. I need to get a list of * columns of matching A,B rows by user_id. I'm using the below query, it has already run for 1 hour in my p4 machine with 100% CPU with no result in sight.

```
SELECT a.* FROM tableA AS a INNER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.user_id = b.user_id;
```

Is there a way to make the query execution fast?

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that both `tableA` and `tableB` has indexes on their `user_id` field.

---

If standard techniques don't help, you can force MySQL to join those two tables in a different order using `STRAIGHT_JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM          tableB AS b /* first process the 900 rows */
STRAIGHT_JOIN tableA AS a /* and find matching rows for every tableB row */
           USING user_id; /* BTW, you could use USING here :) */
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

> STRAIGHT_JOIN is similar to JOIN, except that the left table is always
>   read before the right table. This can be used for those (few) cases
>   for which the join optimizer puts the tables in the wrong order.

Other info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html

> ... The table read order forced by LEFT JOIN or STRAIGHT_JOIN ...
>
> For a LEFT JOIN, if the WHERE condition is always false for the
>   generated NULL row, the LEFT JOIN is changed to a normal join.